# Metamask setup on Iphone creating different accounts to SAME seed phrase through PC

Tags: metamask, accounts, mnemonic

I have a conundrum...

So I created my initial Metamask account on my iphone I'll call this SEED_1.

Using 4 'accounts' over the past year on this phone.

I then decide to start using metamask on my Laptop (we'll call it SEED_2). For some reason I created a new seed phrase, and subsequently 'imported' the accounts from, 'SEED1' wallet.

So everything is working perfectly - I've spent the past few weeks moving some funds around to different blockchains, combining some tokens on one account and moving them out of others.

Now, for some reason (stupidly I may add now) I decide that 'account 3' as it appears on the SEED_2 metamask on laptop, imported from SEED_1 (iphone) actually isn't being used on my 'SEED_2' wallet (the laptop) and I'd tidy it up. So I remove it, which is fine because it's imported and still on the iPhone.

Anyway this account is now no longer viewable from the iPhone and I didn't save the PvtKey.

I've saved the private keys of the other 2 accounts that were created on 'SEED_1' Iphone and restore from seed phrase - BUT, and this is where I believe there is an issue,  I've restored the SEED_1 wallet on PC under a different browser profile so as not to clash with 'SEED_2' and it's adding 'new' accounts, not in anyway related to the ones I initially created on the Iphone.

Summary:

Anyway, long story short It's adding accounts that are completely unrelated to my initial accounts that were created on the Iphone (I've added ~50 to check if it appears) - AND now each time I restore from SEED_1, the same 'new' accounts are appearing.

PROBLEM

So it's doing the right thing, restoring the new accounts BUT the problem is I don't want these 'new' accounts, I want the initial accounts that were setup in Iphone ~12 months ago.

I read that the wallets created on an Iphone are sorted to that device using the seed + password. My worst fear is that by stress clicking and attempting to recover the seed on PC it's somehow overwritten the Iphone accounts that I need to recover.....

SOLUTION?

So I've been trying to use Mnemonic Code Converter and wondering if I can use it on my phone with certain settings in Derivation Path to pull the initial accounts made on the Iphone but I'm not having much luck just trying every alternative setting I can.

any advise or experience in this happening would be profusely helpful